# Magento: Subscription plan for rent products

Tags: magento, store, subscription

I need to create a shop that works with plans for signature.
Each plan offers a number of points every month.
The client will use the points to rent the products (product price is points, not real money).

Is There some extentions for this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [rewards points](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/reward-points-9640.html) plugin for years. You can't go wrong. It's excellent.